# Need the opposite from a query with two times the same value

Tags: mysql

Need the opposite from a query with two times the same value

Im trying to select a value from database that != my id one time but the problem is that my database is stored as below

```
messenger_friendships
user_one_id | user_two_id
1                2
2                1
3                2
2                3
4                1
4                1
```

What i need is to Select the id that isn't my id, one time

i tried

```
 Select user_one_id, user_two_id
FROM messenger_friendships WHERE user_one_id = $myid, user_two_id = $myid
```

but thats totally wrong.

The problem here is that when i put it in a while loop the results will be that i will have myself in my friendslist two times and the other person two times aswell

Comment: Can you think of a way to make this question any less obscure? I can.

Comment: If you included the `expected result` then, even if we can't understand your words, we might understand your need. If `my id = 1` what result do you expect?

Comment: if user_one_id = my id return user_two_id.

Comment: Since the database seems to duplicate the data, wouldn't just `SELECT user_two_id FROM messenger_friendships WHERE user_one_id = $myid` do it? Then you can read the friends of `$myid` from column `user_two_id` without duplicates. Although better database design would be not to have two records for every friend pair.

Comment: @Juhana I disagree. I think this is a valid way of handling reciprocation (assuming that's what's going on here)

Comment: 4 1, 4 1 ??? That don't look right

Answer (score 1):

Using `CASE`:

```sql
Select DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN user_one_id = $myid
        THEN user_two_id
        ELSE user_one_id
    END
FROM messenger_friendships 
WHERE $myid IN (user_one_id, user_two_id)
```

Or using `UNION` (might be faster):

```sql
SELECT user_two_id as friend_id
FROM messenger_friendships
WHERE user_one_id = $myid
UNION
SELECT user_one_id as friend_id
FROM messenger_friendships
WHERE user_two_id = $myid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23faa/8

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_one_id, user_two_id
FROM messenger_friendships 
WHERE user_one_id = 1
```

this would return

```
user_one_id user_two_id
1           2
```

Comment: Yes it would work im sorry but i just realised that my database also gets stored as user_one_id 1 user_two_id 2 and then duplicates so again user_one_id 1 user_two_id 2. so the data gets duplicated.

Comment: Please stop adding words! Add the expected result into you question!!! **Only** when we see that result will we really understand.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try to generate a key by sorting and concatenating the two ids.

I would use a view to simplify the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_friends as
SELECT 
user_one_id,
user_two_id,
IF(user_one_id < user_two_id,
        CONCAT(user_one_id,'-', user_two_id),
        CONCAT(user_two_id,'-', user_one_id)
) as friend_key

FROM messenger_friendships;


SELECT DISTINCT f1.friend_key
FROM view_friends as f1
INNER JOIN view_friends as f2
ON f1.friend_key = f2.friend_key
AND f2.user_one_id = 1;
```